# How to make emacs automatically indent Python code?

Tags: python, emacs

I'm using emacs 24.3 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. How do I make emacs automatically indent lines in Python, like in IDLE? Currently, it does not do that.

Also, in general, how would I do this for any programming language, say, Java or c++?

Comment: http://www.jesshamrick.com/2012/09/18/emacs-as-a-python-ide/

Comment: Does that still work with emacs 24?

Comment: give it a try, I don't use it to be honest.

Comment: I just tried the stuff in there, but emacs is still not auto-indenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try other python modes, like emacs-for-python or elpy, as given by this doc: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Python (though the default mode works fine for me on the same config).

You can install them with package.el (`M-x package-install RET elpy RET`) and call them as explained.

Comment: I used the emacs-for-python, and I love it! Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question, actually: how would I do this for any other language, like java?

Comment: Glad you liked it ! Mmmh… if your mode doesn't already do it, you may remap the RET key to a new-line (`newline`) and indent. This combo is currently done for me with `reindent-then-newline-and-indent`. You can investigate with the help (see `C-h ?`).

Answer (score 3):

Try `electric-indent-mode`.  It will be ebabled by default in Emacs-24.4.  But note that the version in 24.3 probably doesn't work too well in python-mode buffers.

Comment: Add `(electric-indent-mode 1)` in your `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: I tried doing that, but now when I un-indent a line, and press the return key, the previous line indents back to its original position.

Comment: Right: "the version in 24.3 probably doesn't work too well in python-mode".

Answer (score 1):

Open a newline with C-j, you should get the indentation.

Comment: How about auto-identation by just pressing enter?

Comment: The result depends from kind of python-mode resp. customization. With python-mode.el, that's the default, yes.

Comment: I love `C-j`, because that frees up the tab key for GitHub Copilot!